# Fragment Error when extends Fragment instead of FragmentActivity in Fragment Class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a Main Activity page from which I call a list of fragments based on what the user chooses. When I extend Fragment in my fragment class, the replace method in the main activity page throws an error, when I extend fragmentActivity in my fragment page, methods that require (this) context do not work. I am not sure what the work around is for this. Any assistance/guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Code:
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) 
       {

            //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action

            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){


                case R.id.dance:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Dance Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    DANCE fragment_dance = new Dance();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction_dance = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction_dancce.replace(R.id.frame,fragment_aed);
                    fragmentTransaction_dance.commit();
                    return true;
```

Fragment.java

```
public class DANCE extends Fragment implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
{
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();


   AdapterAed danceobjects;

    danceobjects= new AdapterDance (this, 0, dancelisting);

}
```

Having errors in the fragment class where "this" is referenced when I have it extend Fragment, but when it extends FragmentActivity, there are no errors but the mainActivity has the error in the replace method, does not recognize the fragment as a fragment. Thanks for your time

Comment: You could replace your (this) with (getActivity().getApplicationContext())

Comment: That works for the GoogleApiClient.Builder. But fr the new AdapterDance(this,0,dancelisting), I get the error that expected argument should be android.app.activity, but I am supplying android.content.Context. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: Use new AdapterDance(getActivity(),0,dancelisting)